# TFS2013 can't handle large git commits

Tags: git

I've just installed a TFS2013 server (12.0.21005.1 Tfs2013.RTM) and created a collection using Git as the source control provider. I've used both visual studio and Git on Linux to push a few commits, everything works well. However, for large commits, the process fails: Adding a large amount of files, committing that and pushing the branch causes the following output:

```
Counting objects: 17681, done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17680/17680), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTC code = 400
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (17680/17680), 125.43 MiB | 40.53 MiB/s, done.
Total 17680 (delta 7976), reused 1683 (delta 364)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: expected ok/error, helper said '2004}[unintelligible gibberish
Unintelligible gibberish]'
```

Interestingly, this does not seem to show up in any TFS log -  as though it's totally ignored. Even in `tfs:8080/tfs/_oi`, where Git actions do show up (`ReceivePackHandler`), there's no sign of activity. This might be getting rejected by IIS, but I can't understand why and the logs aren't helping.

The added files, by the way, are 405MB in a 15674-file C# project.

Comment: That's odd; proxy server on your network?  Are you on a LAN or a WAN?  Does this take a long time before it fails or does it fail quickly?

Comment: Do IIS Logs and eventlogs on the server say anything?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by using and old version of git. Git 1.7.2.5, which comes with Debian 6, fails as shown above. Git 1.8.1.3 works correctly. I'm guessing it has something to do with changes to the smart HTTP transport. Not exactly what I'd call graceful degradation though...

Comment: So, upgrading to the latest version of Git fixed it?

Comment: That's still odd; I would still love to understand what's failing here.

Comment: @edwardthomson, so would I.